# try catch block does not complete at all

Tags: java, cron, try-catch, batch-processing

I have a runnable JAR that is scheduled by Cron in my ubuntu server. that problem is when after the 1st try catch is finished with no exception then it proceeds to the other It stops. I try to run the `parse()` in separately it works.

This the Main Function:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            if (args.length > 0) {
                if (args[0].compareToIgnoreCase("parse") == 0)
                    Process.parse();
                if (args[0].compareToIgnoreCase("crawl") == 0)
                    Process.crawl();
                if (args[0].compareToIgnoreCase("batch") == 0)
                    Batch();
            }
    static void Batch() throws Exception {

        Date deb = new Date();

        try {
            System.out.println("Batch Start Crawling...");
            Process.crawl(); 
            System.out.println("End of Batch Crawling...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            System.out.println("Batch Start Parsing...");
            Process.parse(); 
            System.out.println("End of Batch Parsing...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is when Batch is Called it successfully run the `crawl()` then during the `parse()` it only prints `Batch Start Parsing....` then no more but when I try to run my crontab separately `parse()` is working smoothly.

Here is my crontab commands:

```
java -jar -Xmx4G -Xms256M /home/desktop/Documents/Run/New_Version/wine.jar batch  - Stop when parse started
java -jar -Xmx4G -Xms256M /home/desktop/Documents/Run/New_Version/wine.jar parse - Successfuly run the parse function
```

Comment: So, you are saying that `Process.parse` doesn't return? Maybe it would help if you could post the code for that method.

Comment: (BTW: `args[0].compareToIgnoreCase("parse") == 0` is more easily expressed as `args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("parse")`)

Comment: I'd also *strongly* recommend starting to follow Java naming conventions as soon as possible... and using braces on even single-statement if statements.

Comment: yes it's kinda weird that happened. my last options is to have a scheduled job for parse only. but my target is after the `crawl()` it should `parse()` the problem if I separate I could not estimate the finish time of `crawl()`

Comment: Process.parse() has to throw exception, so println("End of Batch Parsing") never reached. There is no other option.